# Elasticbeanstalk modifying php-fpm with .ebextensions

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to make modifications on php-fpm configs. I have searched and tried a lot but I am not able to do it.

**Here is my config files;**

This one is not effected anything

```
files:
  "/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      pm.max_children = 500
```

And this one gives me an error.

```
files:
  "/etc/php-fpm.d/00_php-fpm.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      pm.max_children = 500
      pm.start_servers = 5
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What error does the 2nd one give you exactly? Have you tried connecting over `ssh` to your Elastic Beanstalk server to verify `/etc/php-fpm.d` is the folder were the php-fpm config files are located, and that your new files are getting created there?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the [www] header

```
files:
  "/etc/php-fpm.d/00_php-fpm.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [www]
      request_terminate_timeout = 300
```